# How to move the position of a fixed string in a domain generator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Below are the few variables examples inside the `Test` text file that's going to become the web's subdomains.

```
with open("dictionaries/Combined.txt") as i:
Test = [line.rstrip() for line in i]

Test = ['cl', 'portal', 'find', 'signin', 'payment', 'update', 'group', 'verification',
'confirm', 'claim', 'summary', 'recovery', 'ssl', 'view', 'support']

delimeters = ['','-', '.']
web = 'web'
subdomain_count = 1
suffix = ['co.id', 'info', 'id', 'com']
output = []
```

in this code i can control how many subdomains and how many domain name i want to generate

```
for i in range(100):
    outputs = []
    for j in range(subdomain_count):
        outputs.append(random.choice(Test))
    prefix = random.choice(delimeters).join(outputs)
    out = random.choice(delimeters).join([prefix, web])
    tld = random.choice(suffix)
    addr = '.'.join([out, tld])
    output.append(addr)
    Example.write(addr+'\n')

with open("dictionaries/examples.txt") as f:
    websamples = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

To generate the number of output that I want I used this line`for i in range(100):`, and to generate how long the domain name's going to be i used this `for j in range(subdomain_count):` this is the example what i mean by how long the domain can be. if i set the subdomain count to 1 then the output would become something like this `cl.web.info` if i were to add 2 it will become like this `update-cl.web.info`. As you can see the subdomain is now 2 characters longer where the update is now another subdomain has been added into the domain. Here is another example I'll show where i made the `subdomain_count = 1`.

[image: web domain output examples]

From here I got a bit confused, since I have made the web variable at a fixed position where it's always going to be behind the suffix. is there any way where for example I give the `subdomain_count = 3` and I want the web variable have more flexibility in its position like  this `cl.web-update.summary.info` or `web-cl.info.update.info` where it doesn't just stay behind the suffix or the TLD (Top Level Domain)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `random.shuffle` to randomize the items in a list. which gives `web` variable more flexibility in the domain.

```
import random

Test = ['cl', 'portal', 'find', 'signin', 'payment', 'update', 'group', 'verification',
        'confirm', 'claim', 'summary', 'recovery', 'ssl', 'view', 'support']

delimeters = ['', '-', '.']
web = 'web'
subdomain_count = 3
suffix = ['co.id', 'info', 'id', 'com']
output = []
for i in range(5):
    outputs = []
    for j in range(subdomain_count):
        outputs.append(random.choice(Test))
    data = outputs + [web]
    random.shuffle(data)
    prefix = random.choice(delimeters).join(data)
    out = random.choice(delimeters).join([prefix])
    tld = random.choice(suffix)
    addr = '.'.join([out, tld])
    output.append(addr)

print(output)

>>> ['group-summary-web-signin.info', 'web-recovery-signin-verification.co.id', 'paymentupdatewebpayment.co.id', 'update-verification-update-web.id', 'find-group-web-portal.info']
```

Comment: okay i'm being dumb, the solution is rather simple thanks for the help, if you use that  means i can just erase the `web = 'web'` right since, i can make the web variable into a an array by doing this `data = outputs + ['web']` right? @Ramesh

Comment: sure you can do :)